# Is it possible to get input inside a system.out.println in java , if not then how to perform the below code?

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Items sold on Day1 :"+int Day1=sc.nextInt()); //it shows an error
```

Comment: Do the print and the input in separate statements.

Comment: It should be `System.out.println("Items sold on Day1 :"+sc.nextInt());` ([see it here](https://ideone.com/q8GYa2))

Comment: And unrelated: learn about java naming rules. Variable or field names go camelCase, so day1, not Day1!

Comment: Are you trying to print out the variable, or are you trying to print `"Items sold on day 1"` as a prompt for inputting the variable?

Comment: Any feedback on the answer you received? Is your problem is solved (then consider accepting an answer), or do you need additional information?

Answer (score 3):

It is "either or".

Either avoid the local variable:

```
System.out.println("Items sold on Day1 :" + sc.nextInt());
```

Or assign the local variable in a separate statement:

```
int day1=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Items sold on Day1 :" + day1);
```

In other words: you can't declare a variable **within** such an expression/statement.

Which of the two options to prefer really depends on context. When there are *other* usages of that local variable, obviously, you should declare a local variable. If there is only one usage (printing it), then don't use a local variable.